# A conformal map whose Jacobian vanishes at a point is constant?

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry, quasiconformal

Let $f:M \to N$ be a smooth weakly conformal map between connected $d$-dimensional Riemannian manifolds, i.e. $f$ satisfies $df^Tdf =(\det df)^{\frac{2}{d}} \, \text{Id}_{TM}$.

> Assume $d \ge 3$ and that $df=0$ at some point.  Is it true that $f$ is constant?

A proof for the Euclidean case, can be found in "Geometric Function Theory and Non-linear Analysis", by Iwaniec and Martin. Their proof uses the fact both $M,N$ are Euclidean.

If I am not mistaken, a conformal map (in $d\ge3$) is determined by its 2-jet at a point, so it suffices to prove all the second derivatives at the point where $df$ vanishes are zero. (But maybe this wrong; it's possible that the "2-jet determination" only holds for conformal maps whose differentials are everywhere non-zero. I am not sure.)

**Edit:**

David E Speyer proved below that if $f$ is conformal and $df_{x_0}=0$ then all the derivatives of $f$ vanish at $x_0$ (for all orders). Thus, if the above statement about the two-jet-determination is true, the only solutions are indeed constants.

Does anybody know whether or not this "two-jet-determination" hold in the case where we allow the Jacobian to vanish?

Comment: For the record: I deleted a wrong answer I gave earlier in which I gave an example with  derivative 1, not 0. Thanks, @Dmitry, for spotting my mistake.

Answer (score 5):

I am no expert in this field, but I just looked into **Harmonic Morphisms Between Riemannian Manifolds** by *Paul Baird* and *John C. Wood*, specifically into chapter 14. Here they give more general definition of weakly conformal mapping (which it seems is the standard definition). Namely, $f: M \to N$ is weakly conformal at $x\in M$ if
$$
\langle df(X), df(Y) \rangle_{f(x)}= \Lambda(x) \langle X, Y \rangle_x
$$
for some number $\Lambda(x)$.

The Proposition 14.4.3 states that $f$ is weakly conformal at $x$ if one of the three mutually exclusive conditions hold, one of them being $df_x = 0$ and it falls into the *non-degenerate* cases. Few paragraphs later, on page 442, the authors say that non-degenerate weakly conformal maps behave in a similar way to the Riemannian case, namely any non-degenerate mapping is constant provided $\dim M > \dim N.$ I do not see a proof nearby, but then again, I just skimmed the text.

edit:

I don't know why but in the first time I looked at this question I got the impression that it's about semi-Riemannian manifolds. The aforementioned book actually state what the OP is asking for. Unless I misread the question again.

> **Theorem 11.4.6:** Let $f \colon M \to N$ be a non-constant weakly conformal map between manifolds of the same dimension $n \geq 3.$ Then $f$ has no critical points, i.e., $f$ is a conformal local diffeomorphism.

Let me also add that $2$-jet determinacy holds in quite general contexts, see e.g. [Jet-determination of symmetries of parabolic geometries](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.07149) and [Another proof of the Liouville theorem](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3076812), but it seems that the nondegeneracy of $\mathrm{d} f$ is always assumed.

Comment: Thanks, I have also been looking at this book. However, in my question, I assume  $\dim M=\dim N$, so this comment in the book does not seem relevant to this situation.

Comment: Also, I assumed $df_x=0$ at some point $x \in M$ so this is not the non-degenerate case.

Comment: @AsafShachar Sorry, that was a typo. They call $df_x = 0$ non-degenerate.

Answer (score 5):

I am not at all an expert in this field. However, I believe I can show that there are no examples where $Df$ vanishes to finite order. Thus, in particular there are no analytic solutions and, if the OP is right about two-jet-determination, there are no solutions.

Let $f: M \to N$ be a weakly conformal map between Riemannian manifolds of dimension $d>2$. We write $g_M$ and $g_N$ for the metrics on $M$ and $N$, so the conformal condition is that $(Df)^T g^N (Df) = \lambda g^M$ for some scalar valued function $\lambda$ on $M$. If $f$ is singular at $x_0 \in M$, then we must have $\lambda(x_0)=0$, so we must have $Df=0$. We say that $f$ vanishes to order $k$ at $x_0$ if all $r$-fold derivatives of $f$ vanish at $x_0$ for $r<k$ from some $k$-fold derivative doesn't. So we have shown that, if $f$ is singular at $x_0$, then it vanishes to some order $k>1$. We are going to show that there are no solutions which vanish to finite order $>1$.

The problem is local, so we can assume that $M$ and $N$ are open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and we may take $x_0=0$ and $f(x_0)=0$. Furthermore, we may take bases such that $g^M(0)$ and $g^N(0)$ are the standard inner product. These choices still allow us the ability to independently make further orthogonal changes of basis on source and target. We expand $f$ in a Taylor series as $f(x) = f_k(x) + O(|x|^{k+1})$, expand the metrics as $g^M(x) = \mathrm{Id}+ O(|x|)$ and $g^N(y) = \mathrm{Id}+O(|y|)$, and expand the scalar $\lambda$ as $\lambda(x)=\lambda_m(x) +O(|x|^{m+1})$. Here $f_k$ and $\lambda_m$ are nonzero polynomials of degree $k$ and $m$.

The conformal condition is that
$$(Df_k + \cdots)^T (\mathrm{Id}+ \cdots) (Df_k + \cdots) = (\lambda_m + \cdots ) (\mathrm{Id}+ \cdots).$$
Since $f_k \neq 0$, the matrix $Df_k$ is nonzero and thus $(Df_k)^T (Df_k)$ is nonzero. So the leading terms $(Df_k)^T (Df_k)$ and $\lambda_m \mathrm{Id}$ must have matching degrees. We deduce that $m = 2k-2$ and $(Df_k)^T (Df_k) = \lambda_{m} \mathrm{Id}$.

Thus, the polynomial map $f_k$ is conformal between $\mathbb{R}^d$ and itself, with the standard Euclidean structure. This contradicts the result of Iwaniec and Martin cited by the OP.

---

Also, in the case $k=2$, we can verify that there is no solution by a direct computation. I will rename my variables -- my goal is to show that there is no conformal map $f: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$ given by quadratic polynomials such that $(Df)(x)^T (Df)(x) = \lambda(x) \mathrm{Id}$ where $\lambda$ is a polynomial of degree $2$. Let the components of $f$ be $f(x) = \tfrac{1}{2} (x^T P_1 x, x^T P_2 x, \cdots, x^T P_n x)$ and let $\lambda(x) = \tfrac{1}{2} x^T Q x$, where the $P_i$ and $Q$ are symmetric.

We can break the matrix $Df$ up into rows:
$$Df = \begin{bmatrix} x^T P_1 \\ x^T P_2 \\ \vdots \\ x^T P_n \end{bmatrix}.$$
Our given condition is that $(Df)(x)^T (Df)(x) = \lambda(x) \mathrm{Id}$; since $\lambda(x)$ is nonzero, we can work in the field of rational functions of $x$ and deduce that we also have $(Df)(x) (Df)(x)^T = \lambda(x) \mathrm{Id}$, giving
$$\begin{bmatrix} x^T P_1 \\ x^T P_2 \\ \vdots \\ x^T P_n \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} P_1 x & P_2 x & \cdots & P_n x \end{bmatrix} =
\tfrac{1}{2} (x^T Q x) \mathrm{Id}.$$
So, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$, we have
$$x^T P_i P_j x = \begin{cases} \tfrac{1}{2} x^T Q x & i = j \\ 0 & i \neq j \end{cases}.$$
We can't deduce that $P_i P_j = \tfrac{1}{2} Q$ from this, since $P_i P_j$ may not be symmetric. But we do deduce
$$P_i P_j + P_j P_i = \begin{cases} Q & i=j \\ 0 & i \neq j \end{cases}. \quad (\ast)$$

Making an orthogonal change of basis, we may assume that $Q$ is diagonal. Let the eigenvalues of $Q$ be $q_1$, $q_2$, ... $q_k$ with multiplicities $d_1$, $d_2$, ..., $d_k$. Since $Q = 2 P_i^2$, all the $P_i$ commute with $Q$ and thus they are block diagonal with blocks of size $d_1$, $d_2$, ..., $d_k$. Thus, we may solve the equation $(\ast)$ separately in each block, and may thus assume that $Q$ is diagonal; say $Q = q \mathrm{Id}$. Since $Q = 2 P_i^2$, we have $q>0$; rescaling each $P$ by $\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2 q}}$, we may assume that $Q = \mathrm{Id}$.

Thus, $(\ast)$ becomes 
$$P_i P_j + P_j P_i = \begin{cases} \mathrm{Id} & i=j \\ 0 & i \neq j \end{cases}. \quad (\ast)$$
In other words, $\mathbb{R}^{d_i}$ is a representation of the Clifford algebra on $d$ generators with $d_i \leq d$. For $d>2$, this is impossible.
(We are talking about the algebra labeled $C\ell_{d,0}$ in [Wikipedia's table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_Clifford_algebras).)

Comment: Thanks, this is very interesting. Just to be sure, you provided the proof there are no polynomial solutions for $k=2$ for completeness, right? (I guess your point was that this could be proved directly, without referring to the Euclidean theorem?). I mean, as you already said, from the earlier Euclidean result, you concluded that there are no such maps for any $k$, right?

Comment: @AsafShachar That's right. I wasn't able to find Iwaniec and Martin, so I wanted to see what I could do by just thinking.

Comment: Plus, if you are right about 2-jet determination, then the two parts of my post are a complete proof without appealing to Iwaniec and Martin.

Answer (score 2):

In a different direction, there are solutions where $f$ is $C^1$ and the metric $g_M$ is $C^0$. Let $\phi : \mathbb{R}_{>0} \to \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ be a $C^1$ function such that $\lim_{s \to 0^+} \phi(s) = \lim_{s \to 0^+} s \tfrac{\phi'(s)}{\phi(s)} = 0$. An example is $\phi(s) = \tfrac{1}{-\log s}$. (Or rather, that function near $0$ smoothed out somehow to not blow up at $s=1$.)

Write $s$ for the function $\sum x_i^2$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $M=N=\mathbb{R}^n$ and define $f:M \to N$ by $f(\vec{x}) = \phi(s)\ \vec{x}$. Let $g_N$ be the standard metric and define $g_M = \tfrac{1}{\phi(s)^2} f^{\ast} g_N$ on $M \setminus \{ 0 \}$. I claim that $g_M$ extends continuously to $0$.

We compute: The Jacobian of $f$ at the point $\vec{x}$ is
$$J = \phi(s) \mathrm{Id} + \phi'(s)\  \vec{x} \ \vec{x}^T.$$
Using the identity $\vec{x}^T \vec{x}=s$, we compute:
$$g_M = \tfrac{1}{\phi(s)^2} J J^T = \mathrm{Id} + \left(2 \tfrac{\phi'(s)}{\phi(s)} + \tfrac{s \phi'(s)^2}{\phi(s)^2} \right) \vec{x} \ \vec{x}^T .$$
We will show that the second term zpproaches $0$ as $\vec{x} \to 0$. Note that each entry of $\vec{x}^T \vec{x}$ is $O(|\vec{x}|^2) = O(s)$. So each entry in the second term is bounded by 
$$2 \tfrac{s \phi'(s)}{\phi(s)} + \left( \tfrac{s \phi'(s)}{\phi(s)} \right)^2$$
and we assumed $\tfrac{s \phi'(s)}{\phi(s)} \to 0$.

Unfortunately, the hypothesis that $\tfrac{s \phi'(s)}{\phi(s)} \to 0$ gives $\tfrac{\phi'}{\phi} = o(s^{-1})$ so $\log |\phi| = o(\log s)$ and $\phi$ must approach $0$ more slowly than any $s^{\epsilon}$. So $f(x,0,0,\ldots,0)$ has derivative $0$ at $0$ but is larger than any $x^{1+\epsilon}$. So this method can't be pushed to $C^2$ functions.