# Are conformal maps between Riemannian manifolds real-analytic?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry, analytic-functions, real-analytic-structures

This is a [cross-post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2916649/are-conformal-maps-between-riemannian-manifolds-real-analytic).

> Let $M,N$ be oriented smooth ($C^{\infty}$) $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifolds, and let $f:M \to N$ be a smooth orientation-preserving weakly* conformal map.
>
> Do there exist real-analytic structures on $M,N$ that make $f$ real-analytic?

I only assume the metrics are $C^{\infty}$.
Every smooth manifold [has a unique real-analytic structure](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8789/can-every-manifold-be-given-an-analytic-structure) (up to diffeomorphism) compatible with its smooth structure.

A  reasonable starting point would be to know whether every $C^{\infty}$ conformal map between real-analytic manifolds with real-analytic metrics is real-analytic. (I don't know a reference for that; anyway, what I am asking seems harder).

*A weakly conformal map is a map whose differential at every point is either conformal or zero. (This is equivalent to $df^Tdf =(\det df)^{\frac{2}{n}} \, \text{Id}_{TM}$).

*Motivation:*

I am trying to understand [if smooth weakly conformal maps whose differential vanishes at a point are constant](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/308102/a-conformal-map-whose-jacobian-vanishes-at-a-point-is-constant) (for dimensions $n \ge 3$). This seems to be [the case for analytic maps](https://mathoverflow.net/a/308673/46290), hence my interest in the possible analyticity of such maps.

---

For the Euclidean case, this follows directly by [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(conformal_mappings)):

For $n=2$, every such map is complex-analytic. Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open subset, $n \ge 3$, and let $f:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth conformal map. By Liouville's theorem, $f$ is of the form
$$ f(x)=b+\alpha\frac{1}{|x-a|^\epsilon}A(x-a),$$

where $A$ is an orthogonal matrix, and $\epsilon \in \{0,2\}, b \in \mathbb{R}^n,\alpha \in \mathbb{R},a \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \Omega$.

So, up to translations and dilations,
$ f(x)=\frac{A x}{|x|^2}$ (where $ 0 \notin \Omega$) which is real-analytic as a multiplication of two analytic maps. ($1/x^2$ is analytic on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$).

Comment: While there is an analytic structure on the manifold, the Riemannian metric will not necessarily be real analytic. Does it bother you?

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz No, I am OK with the metrics to be only $C^{\infty}$ but not real analytic. (Although the case where the metrics *are* analytic is also interesting I guess. I assume that in that case, conformal maps-in high dimensions, do need to be analytic, but I don't know a reference for that).

Answer (score 8):

As essentially follows from your argument in the comment to Piotr Hajlasz's answer (now deleted), for $f\colon M\to N$ to be a counterexample, it cannot be a diffeomorphism. Because then you could just pick any analytic structure on $N$, pull it back to $M$ by $f$ and make $f$ trivially analytic.

With that in mind, one can think of counterexamples already in 1-dimension. For instance let $(N,g_N) = (M,g_M) = (\mathbb{R},dx^2)$, where $dx^2$ is the metric that appears flat with respect to some global coordinate $x$. Let
$$
  f(x) = \begin{cases}
    (x+\epsilon) e^{-1/(x+\epsilon)^2} & x<-\epsilon \\
    0 & -\epsilon\le x \le \epsilon \\
    (x-\epsilon) e^{-1/(x-\epsilon)^2} & \epsilon < x
  \end{cases} .
$$
It is locally a diffeomorphism if you consider it as a map from $\mathbb{R}\setminus [-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ to $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$. But there is no pair of analytic structures on $\mathbb{R}$ that would make $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ analytic. If $f$ were analytic (with respect to any analytic atlas), then it could not vanish on any open set, while not being globally zero. But since we are in 1-dimension, any map is weakly conformal. So then $f\colon M \to N$ is weakly conformal, but can never be made analytic.

<del>Higher dimensional examples could be generated from this one by using rotational symmetry and basically reducing to the 1-dimensional case.</del>

Comment: Could you spell out the higher dimensional argument in your last paragraph? It can't work in dimension $2$ because of Louisville's theorem and I spent some time trying to make a construction like this work in dimension 3 and failing when I thought about the OP's earlier question.

Comment: For example, I considered maps of the form $\vec{x} \mapsto \phi(|\vec{x}|) \vec{x}$ where $\phi : \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ is $0$ on $[0,1]$ and $>0$ thereafter. But I got that you need $\phi'(s)/\phi(s)$ to be bounded near $s=1$, so $\log \phi(s)$ is bounded, so $\phi$ can't go to $0$.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer, hmm, I think that I was overly optimistic when I wrote that. I basically had in mind the same idea as you, and now see that it doesn't easily work, just as you say. Sorry!

Answer (score 4):

This is not an answer. Just a possible vector of attack for this problem.

According to the Theorem 11.4.6 of Harmonic Morphisms Between Riemannian Manifolds by Paul Baird and John C. Wood, every non-constant weakly conformal map between manifolds of the same dimension $n\geq 3$ is a conformal local diffeomorphism. The automorphism group of $(M, [g])$ is a Lie group whose Lie algebra is the algebra of conformal Killing vector fields.

According to the Theorem 3.8 of [Normal BGG solutions and polynomials](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.0799) every conformal Killing vector field is given by a polynomial expression (of degree at most 2) in normal coordinates and normal frame. Given a Cartan geometry $(\pi: \mathcal{G} \to M, \omega \in \Omega^1(\mathcal{G}, \mathfrak{g})$, these normal coordinates and frames are given by flow flow of $\omega^{-1}(X)$ and by projection of that flow through $\pi.$

Comment: Thanks. Does your second comment (regarding the conformal vector fields) imply that such conformal maps are real-analytic? (It seems to me that the normal coordinates themselves could be only $C^{\infty}$ but not real-analytic, since the metrics are not assumed to be real-analytic, but maybe I am confused here).

Comment: @AsafShachar I don't know. These coordinates and frames are given by flows of certain vector fields comming from the Cartan connection.

Comment: Why doesn't your first comment answer the question in dimension $n > 3$? It seems you can pick a real analytic structure on the base and pull back sufficiently small charts via the local diffeomorphism to give a real analytic structure on the domain for which (in these charts) the map $f$ is the identity. I must be missing something.

Comment: @MikeMiller Because I didn't have enough coffee today.

Comment: You at least had enough to find these lovely references :)

Comment: I checked Baird and Wood, and the result is for $n \geq 3$, not just $n>3$.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer So with Liouville's theorem and Igor's answer, this should give a full answer to the question, yes?